# Converting time to 24h format

Tags: sql, ms-access

First, I convert a time in the format hhmm to hh:nn (24hr format)

```
Format(TimeSerial(Left([Table].[TIME],2),Right([TABLE].[TIME],2),0),"hh:nn:ss")
```

Next, I am trying to combine it with a Date, but the time format changes back to 12h automatically:

```
 TABLE.DATE= Format([TABLE].[DATE] & " " & Format(TimeSerial(Left([Table].[TIME],2),Right([TABLE].[TIME],2),0),"hh:nn:ss"),"mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn");
```

How can I keep the date in a 24h format within this query?

Answer (score 0):

Always separate value handling from display.

If your table fields are of data type Date, you can simply do:

```
=Table!Date+Table!Time
```

The format is for display only.